# Permission denied (publickey) Could not read from remote repository

Tags: android

While uploading source code on Git from Android studio, Github gives error permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: This is more like git question rather than Android.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a pretty generic permissions issue.

You may get some useful results from `git remote -v` for the following items to review:

- Whether you are pushing to a repository you have permission to and which exists
- How you set up your keys (did you? are they global or just for this repo?)
- Whether you cloned via HTTPS or git protocol